# Access denied error when creating Personal View in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am getting access denied errors when trying to create a personal view in a Sharepoint library.  I have no problems creating public views.  I have full control access to the site and library.

Other users on the library are also experiencing this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs to Sharepoint.Stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have full control but are you also an administrator. Full Control can have their permissions adjusted by an admin

Comment: Yes I am an admin as well.  This also happens to all the other users on the library.